# Azure AD Service Principal client credentials grant 535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful accessing smtp.office365.com via XOAUTH2 SASL SMTP

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, smtp, office365, mailkit

I have followed this guide on how to use client credentials grant flow to authenticate IMAP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#use-client-credentials-grant-flow-to-authenticate-imap-and-pop-connections

The app registration has the following permissions:

[image]

I have successfully given my application's service principal access to the mailbox I wish to read:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "john.smith@contoso.com" -User <SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID> -AccessRights FullAccess
```

[image]

And the application's service principal has `SendAs` rights to the mailbox used.

```
Add-RecipientPermission -Identity "john.smith@contoso.com" -Trustee <SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID> -AccessRights SendAs
```

https://serverfault.com/a/1110785

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mailbox-permissions?view=exchserver-2019&viewFallbackFrom=exchonline-ww

[image]

The obtained access token looks good with roles matching what I want to do:

[image]

I have used both `Microsoft.Identity.Client` and `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to get a token successfully and I have used `MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient` to send emails. I can get access to the mailbox via IMAP using `MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient`. See this question:

[Azure AD Service Principal client credentials grant AUTHENTICATE failed accessing outlook.office365.com mailbox via IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558889/azure-ad-service-principal-client-credentials-grant-authenticate-failed-accessin)

IMAP and SMTP settings from:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353

The guide does say:

> Note As per the current test with SMTP Oauth 2.0 client credential
> flow with non-interactive sign in is not supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#smtp-protocol-exchange

What I can't understand is why they then have a `Office 365 Exchange Online` `Application permission` called `Mail.Send` that `Allows the app to send mail as any user without a signed-in user`. Application permissions states that they should be used when *Your application runs as a background service or daemon without a signed-in user*.

[image]

[image]

Similar question:

[Office 365 XOAUTH2 for SMTP on native clients 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346084/office-365-xoauth2-for-smtp-on-native-clients-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccess)

Using `Mail.Send` with `Delegated permissions` I can send an email using SMTP with the mailbox I wish to send as. Code example for that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73728638/3850405

Code:

```
    var clientId = "";
    var tenantId = "";
    var clientSecret = "";
    //I have also tried with var outlookDomain = "smtp.office365.com";
    var outlookDomain = "outlook.office365.com";
    var email = "info@example.com";

    var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

    string[] scopes = new string[] {
    "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
    };

    var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
    .ExecuteAsync();

    string accessToken = result.AccessToken;

    var oauth2Test = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(email, accessToken);
    var client = new ImapClient();
    await client.ConnectAsync(outlookDomain, 993, SecureSocketOptions.Auto, cancellationToken);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2Test);
    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);

    var message = new MimeMessage();
    message.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(_settings.UserName));
    message.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("info2@example.com"));
    message.Subject = "Test";
    message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = @"Oscar Testar" };

    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        await smtpClient.ConnectAsync("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls, cancellationToken);
        if (smtpClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("OAUTHBEARER") || smtpClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("XOAUTH2"))
        {
            //Exception here:
            await smtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2Test);
        }
        await smtpClient.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken);
        await smtpClient.DisconnectAsync(true, cancellationToken);
    }
```

> MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: 5.7.3 Authentication
> unsuccessful [AB1C230CA0059.SWEP280.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]'

If I try with outlookDomain set to `smtp.office365.com` and scopes set to `https://smtp.office365.com/.default` I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 'AADSTS500011: The
> resource principal named https://smtp.office365.com was not found in
> the tenant named <NAME>. This can happen if the application has not
> been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by
> any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication
> request to the wrong tenant.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to send e-mail from an application directly using an oauth-client, without using an actual user/mailbox-account? I was trying to do the same. From my understanding this is not possible. You are always required to start an interactive login and use the token subsequently generated for the user and not the client. [....non-interactive sign in is not supported.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#smtp-protocol-exchange)

Comment: The background service approach seems to be supported by [grap-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mime-message), for which the client permission are used. As far as I understand. SMTP does not seem to be an option, see also https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/1383#issuecomment-1141319806 and https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/1126