# Can MailKit be used to send email using graph on azure

Tags: azure, email, mailkit

In the past azure (outlook 365) let users use SMTP to send email from apps, but in the past year this has changed and tokens granted by Micrsoft.Client.Identity cannot be used in the MailKit SmtpClient unless the users outlook365 account removes default azure security. I am not sure why they did this but we have been looking for a way to send emails through our apps.

We found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806662/using-oauth2-to-send-email-via-office365-c-sharp) and [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sending-smtp-email-microsoft-graph-oauth-using-vbnet-elie-karkafy/) on sending email using Microsoft graph, and this works. In the article the code sets up a json email message. I want to know if we can use MailKit to set up an email message and send using a MailKit method, or would we just need to serialize email created using MailKit into json and then do the PostAsync as the article does.

Comment: MailKit can be used to send email using Microsoft Graph on Azure. However, it requires additional configuration to use OAuth2 authentication with MailKit. Instead, it is recommended to use the Microsoft Graph SDK to send emails using OAuth2 authentication. The SDK provides a simpler and more secure way to interact with Microsoft Graph APIs.

Comment: References:

-   [Outlook mail API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview#why-integrate-with-outlook-mail)
-   [Quickstart: Send email with SMTP (smtp-method-smtpclient)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/send-email-smtp/send-email-smtp?pivots=smtp-method-smtpclient#prerequisites)

Answer (score 0):

***Yes, you can make use of Malkit to send mail like below:***

Create an Azure AD application and assign below API permissions:

[image]

Grant access to the user:

```sql
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "xxx@example.com" -User ServicePrincipalID -AccessRights FullAccess
```

For sample, I used **client credential flow** to generate the token by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://outlook.office.com/.default
```

[image]

***By using the above token you call send mail like below:***

```cs
var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create (clientId)
    .WithAuthority ($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
    .WithCertificate (certificate) // or .WithClientSecret (clientSecret)
    .Build ();
 
var scopes = new string[] {
    // For IMAP and POP3, use the following scope
    "https://ps.outlook.com/.default"

    // For SMTP, use the following scope
    // "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
};

var authToken = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient (scopes).ExecuteAsync ();
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (accountEmailAddress, authToken.AccessToken);

using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    await client.ConnectAsync ("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync (oauth2);
    await client.DisconnectAsync (true);
}
```

But it is suggested to make use of Microsoft Graph API to send mail for sing OAuth2 authentication. Refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958442/can-microsoft-graph-send-email-using-authentication-code-flow) by me

**References:**

[Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)

[MailKit/ExchangeOAuth2.md at master · jstedfast/MailKit · GitHub](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md)  by jstedfast