# Can microsoft graph send email using authentication code flow

Tags: azure, email, msal

Found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806662/using-oauth2-to-send-email-via-office365-c-sharp) and [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sending-smtp-email-microsoft-graph-oauth-using-vbnet-elie-karkafy/) on sending email using Microsoft graph. On Azure we have our application registration, and we have added Mail.Send as an app permission, as stated in the article and the code works. But, from my understanding, the code can use any users email. We want to use authentication code flow, as in the code below, so we have a registered user. However, we get a forbidden response. Are we doing something wrong, or does the authentication code flow not work for graph send email.

```
    public static string ClientId = "ClientId Here";
    public static string TenantId = "TenantId Here";

    public static string RedirectUri = "http://localhost;

    public static string AppAuthority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0";


        _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create ( ClientId )
            .WithAuthority ( AppAuthority )
            .WithRedirectUri ( RedirectUri )
            .Build ();



        TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization ( _clientApp.UserTokenCache );


            // Set up the Microsoft Graph API endpoint and version
        string graphApiEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";

        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        var app = _clientApp;

        List<string> scope = 
            new List<string> ()
            {
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
            };


        IAccount firstAccount;

        var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync ();
        firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault ();

        try
        {
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent ( scope, firstAccount )
                .ExecuteAsync ();
        }
        catch ( MsalUiRequiredException ex )
        {
            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive ( scope )
                    .WithAccount ( firstAccount )
                    .WithPrompt ( Prompt.SelectAccount )
                    .ExecuteAsync ();
            }
            catch ( MsalException msalex )
            {}
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            return;
        }

        if ( authResult == null )
            return;




        // Set up the user's email address and message content
        string userEmail = "foouser@foo.com";
        string messageSubject = "Test email";
        string messageBody = "This is a test email sent via Microsoft Graph";


        // Set up the HTTP client and add the access token to the authorization header
        var httpClient = new HttpClient ();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue ( "Bearer", authResult.AccessToken );

        // Set up the email message
        var emailMessage = new
        {
            message = new
            {
                subject = messageSubject,
                body = new
                {
                    contentType = "Text",
                    content = messageBody
                },
                toRecipients = new []
                {
                    new
                    {
                        emailAddress = new
                        {
                            address = userEmail
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Convert the email message to a JSON string and send the email via Microsoft Graph

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
        string jsonMessage = JsonSerializer.Serialize ( emailMessage, options );


        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync ( $"{graphApiEndpoint}/users/{userEmail}/sendMail", new StringContent ( jsonMessage, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" ) );

        if ( response.IsSuccessStatusCode )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( "Email sent successfully." );
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( "Failed to send email. Status code: " + response.StatusCode );
        }



    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;

    using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

    namespace WpfApp1
    {
        static class TokenCacheHelper
        {
            static TokenCacheHelper ()
            {
                try
                {
                    string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath ( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData );

                    // Combine the base folder with your specific folder....
                    string localFolder = Path.Combine ( folder, "Local" );

                    // CreateDirectory will check if every folder in path exists and, if not, create them.
                    // If all folders exist then CreateDirectory will do nothing.
                    Directory.CreateDirectory ( localFolder );

                    var localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath ( Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData );

                    // For packaged desktop apps (MSIX packages, also called desktop bridge) the executing assembly folder is read-only. 
                    // In that case we need to use Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.Path + "\msalcache.bin" 
                    // which is a per-app read/write folder for packaged apps.
                    // See https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes


                    CacheFilePath = Path.Combine ( localAppData, ".msalcache.bin3" );
                }
                catch ( System.InvalidOperationException )
                {
                    // Fall back for an unpackaged desktop app
                    CacheFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().Location + ".msalcache.bin3";
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Path to the token cache
            /// </summary>
            public static string CacheFilePath { get; private set; }

            private static readonly object FileLock = new object ();

            public static void BeforeAccessNotification ( TokenCacheNotificationArgs args )
            {
                lock ( FileLock )
                {
                    args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3 ( File.Exists ( CacheFilePath )
                            ? ProtectedData.Unprotect ( File.ReadAllBytes ( CacheFilePath ),
                                                     null,
                                                     DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser )
                            : null );
                }
            }

            public static void AfterAccessNotification ( TokenCacheNotificationArgs args )
            {
                // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
                if ( args.HasStateChanged )
                {
                    lock ( FileLock )
                    {
                        // reflect changes in the persistent store
                        File.WriteAllBytes ( CacheFilePath,
                                           ProtectedData.Protect ( args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3 (),
                                                                 null,
                                                                 DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser )
                                          );
                    }
                }
            }

            internal static void EnableSerialization ( ITokenCache tokenCache )
            {
                tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess ( BeforeAccessNotification );
                tokenCache.SetAfterAccess ( AfterAccessNotification );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note**: You can send mail through Authorization code flow. But this flow requires delegated permissions not application permissions. Hence grant **`Mail.send`** delegated API permission to the Azure AD application.

Create an Azure Ad application and grant **`Mail.send`** delegated Api permission:

[image]

Now I generated **auth-code** using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated **access token** via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID  
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code  
code:code  
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:Secret
```

[image]

Make sure to decode the **access token** and check if the scope is displayed:

[image]

Now by using the above access token, **I am able to send mail successfully:**

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
Content-type: application/json

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[user: sendMail - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)